# Problems printing € symbol with jspdf

Tags: jspdf

I am tryng to print in my PDF document an Euro/Dollar/Pound Symbol with jsPdf,

i have a really simple piece of code like...

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(10,10,'€');
```

And the result is just a rare words as you can see in the picture below.

[image]

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They solution that i found, is just import a font that contain the € symbol...
I followed the example of this web.

Link: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

inside the folder examples/js/basic.js you can see how to import a font.

remember that you have to pass a base64 code to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using jsPDF you are initially limited which Fonts you can use Unless you import an embedment which will bloat the PDF size

One way around a missing symbol such as Euro is to either draw as primatives or adapt any similar character by additions and masking (whiteout).

Here is such an example to draw Euro shape at 10,10 as requested.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.setFont("Symbol", "normal");
doc.text("Ì", 10.3, 10);
doc.text("-", 10, 09.9);
doc.text("-", 10, 10.4);
doc.setFillColor(255, 255, 255);
// Filled square
doc.rect(12.5, 7, 3, 4, "F");
```

[image]