# Using Js PDF Not able to print the symbol ≥ , ≤

Tags: jspdf

Using Js PDF Not able to print the symbol  ≥ , ≤  in the output we get "e" d .we try differnt Font like noto sans but did not work

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. As it stands we can only *guess* at what you are doing and which part is wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for extra fonts above and beyond Symbol or ZapfDingbats If they have those symbols

[image]

Answer (score -1):

just import a font that contain the  symbol.

Link: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

inside the folder examples/js/basic.js you can see how to import a font.

remember that you have to pass a base64 code to make it works.

Comment: Would be nice if you could link to the original answer instead of duplicating it 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52534410/3183454